# Clojure: boot won't display log

Tags: clojure

I am writing some Clojure for my hobby project. Right now I am implementing boot tasks for migrating sql files.

I have following code that handles migration.

```
; when executed from repl logs whatever printed by println
(defn migrate-pending [config]
  (if (migration-table-exists? config)
    (for [to-migrate (get-pending-migrations config)]
      (migrate to-migrate config))
    (create-migration-table config)))

; this consumes the log
(core/deftask migrate
  "Migrate up"
  []
  (migrate-pending pg-uri))
```

`migrate` function simply prints the value it gets. `boot` seems to consume the log but when executed through `repl` it prints the log.

Is this expected?

Comment: If you replace `for` with `doseq`, does that change things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be doing something that is side-effecting from `for`, which 'yields a lazy sequence of evaluations of expr'. You should instead use `doseq`.

Better than writing functions that print things is to write functions that return something.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try to wrap by dorun function and it inforce any side effect

[clojure docs - dorun](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dorun)

Comment: this throws an exception `Unable to resolve symbol: to-migrate in this context`